# Javascript touch events support for Windows8 Metro App

Tags: jquery, touch

I am working on porting iPad application to Windows8 Metro application but having problem to convert all the touch related events with in limited time period.

I would like to know whether there is any existing libraries which support Windows8 Metro apps touch events, and would be better if working with jQuery too. FYI, I am using jQuery touch events in iPad version.

Any kind of support will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.